# How to edit specific parts of a file based on user input in C?

Tags: c, string, file, scanf, fopen

I am doing a homework assignment that requires me to create a program for making a dictionary. Most of my assignment is done, but I am stuck on the most complicated part. The part of the assignment I'm stuck on reads:

> Editing a Dictionary (E)
>
> ```
> Insert a new word (I) (15 points)
>     If the word is available, it should alert a message.
>     Otherwise, insert the new word
> Delete a word (D) (15 points)
>     If the word is not available, it should alert a message.
>     Otherwise, delete the word
> Editing a word (U) (10 points)
>     If the word is not available, it should alert a message
> ```

Currently the file I am working with looks like this:

> ---
>
> ```
> Name of product: Dictionary
> Description: Spanish to English Dictionary
> Developer: Robert
> Date of Creation: 12/02/2017
> Number of words: 0
> ***************************************************************************
> 1. Red Rojo
> 2. Cat Gato
> 3. Apple Manzana
> 4. Love Amor
> 5. Car Carro
> ```

and I am wondering how I can read, and do the operations above. Most of the stuff on google is very complicated for my current skillset. Here is what I have so far? Can someone ELI5 the general process of what I should be doing in this case? Should I be using structs? How can I interact with the file in the way my professor wants me to? Here is my basic code I have for this section so far:

```
int editDictionary(char *oDict) {
    char array[1000];
    char temp[100];
    FILE * dictPtr; // dictPtr = dictionary.dic file pointer

    /* fix directory for dictionaries */
    strcat(temp,"./dicts/");
    strcat(temp,oDict);
    strcpy(oDict,temp);

    /* open dictPtr file for rw */
    dictPtr = fopen (oDict,"a+");
    fscanf(dictPtr,"%s",array[1]);

    /* text scan values */
    for(int i = 0; i <5; i ++) printf("%s", array[i]);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `strcat(temp,"./dicts/");` is trying to concatenate to an *uninitialised* array. It should be `strcpy(temp,"./dicts/");` . And then you have `fscanf(dictPtr,"%s",array[1]);` but please *enable compiler warnings*. I don't know why you try to skip the first character of `array` because you go on to index it.

Comment: Are you supposed to do these on text files or binary files(using `struct`)?

Comment: They are essentially .txt files with the .dic extension @vishal-wadhwa

Answer (score 1):

Your task is pretty tedious and requires knowledge of some inbuilt functions in `C`.

Since, this is your homework assignment, providing the entire code to you would do no good in improving your current skillset. So, I will provide the code for performing the `delete` operation the dictionary which is the trickiest of all. Rest you have to figure out yourself. The code in `delete_dict` is more than enough to help you write other functions.

I've added the explanations in the code for most of the functions used but you should still look up their documentation to understand what each function does.

#### Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const char *WORD_COUNT_LABEL = "Number of words: ";

void delete_word(const char *filename, const char *word)
{
    //add alerts
    char read[100];
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");
    int exists = 0; //the count of words that exist
    //check if word exists
    //fgets is used to read a line into the buffer/temp memory read
    while (fgets(read, 100, f))
    {
        //strstr - finds substring
        if (strstr(read, word))
        {
            exists++;
        }
    }
    if (exists == 0)
    {
        fclose(f);
        return;
    }

    //The main objective to read the file two times is
    //because we want to edit the NUMBER_OF_WORDS in the file as well

    //now we know that a word exists
    //so move flie pointer to beginning
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);

    FILE *nf = fopen("dict_t.txt", "w");
    int count;
    char num[10];
    char *p;
    while (fgets(read, 100, f))
    {
        //if word count label is found update it
        //return the pointer to the location of match
        if (p = strstr(read, WORD_COUNT_LABEL))
        {
            p += strlen(WORD_COUNT_LABEL);
            //incrementing the pointer to the position where number is to be updated

            count = atoi(p); //converts integer from char * to int
            count -= exists;
            sprintf(num, "%d", count); //converts interger from int to char *
            strcpy(p, num);            //copy new number at that location
            strcat(p, "\n");
        }
        else if (p = strstr(read, word))
        {
            //if we find the word to be deleted
            //we set the first character in read as NULL
            //so that nothing is written onto the new file.
            read[0] = '\0';
        }
        //writes char * to file
        fputs(read, nf);
    }
    //rest is self explanatory
    fclose(nf);
    fclose(f);
    remove(filename);
    rename("dict_t.txt", filename);
}
```